# need assistance with HTML , beginner over here

Tags: html

So , lately i tried to mess around with html , it went well , until i tried to add a link .
so link isn't working and it's taking me to the files directory where the html file is located and saying err_file_not_found

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>hello World</title>
    <head>Hello World !</head>
    <header>2nd sentence</header>
    <h1>3rd sentence</h1>
    <h2>4th sentence</h2>
    <h3>5th sentence</h3>
    <h4>6th sentences</h4>
    <h5>7th sentence</h5>
    <h6>8th sentence</h6>
    <p>this is a regular sentence.<br>
        regular sentences contain many words.<br>
        by the end of this day , i will learn new 
    things and remember old ones.<br>
        i learned how to write words in 
    <em>diagonal</em> .<br>
        i also learned how to write words in 
    <strong>bold</strong><br>
    <ul>my first list
        <p>list item 1</p>
        <p>list item 2</p>
        <p>list item 3</p>
        <p>list item 4</p>
    </ul>
    <ol>my secon list
        <p>list item 1</p>
        <p>list item 2</p>
        <p>list item 3</p>
        <p>list item 4</p>
        </ol>
        <hr> some thing horizontal
        <a href="www.wikipedia.org">this is an example 
    of a web page</a>
    </p>
```

Comment: There are a few issues with the above. The `title` should be within the `head` section. The `head` section cannot contain plain text as here - only other suitable tags. There is no `body` section and there are no opening/closing `html` tags

Comment: Also - a `p` tag is not a valid child of an ordered list (`ol`),  nor is it valid within a `ul` element unless a child of `li`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use at URLs http:// or https:// before the URL (Depends on the Website, in Wikipedias Case https). In your case your Browser thinks that it is a file.

Comment: Thanks , i got it , and it worked with http and https as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guide - to correct your HTML markup perhaps this will be useful as it encapsulates the comments I made above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <header>2nd sentence</header>
        
        <h1>3rd sentence</h1>
        <h2>4th sentence</h2>
        <h3>5th sentence</h3>
        <h4>6th sentences</h4>
        <h5>7th sentence</h5>
        <h6>8th sentence</h6>
        
        <p>
            this is a regular sentence.<br>
            regular sentences contain many words.<br>
            by the end of this day , i will learn new 
            things and remember old ones.
            
            <br>
            
            i learned how to write words in 
            <em>diagonal</em> .
            
            <br>
            
            i also learned how to write words in 
            <strong>bold</strong>
            
            <br>
            
            <ul>
                <li>my first list</li>
                <li><p>list item 1</p></li>
                <li><p>list item 2</p></li>
                <li><p>list item 3</p></li>
                <li><p>list item 4</p></li>
            </ul>
            <ol>
                <li>my secon list</li>
                <li><p>list item 1</p></li>
                <li><p>list item 2</p></li>
                <li><p>list item 3</p></li>
                <li><p>list item 4</p></li>
            </ol>
            
            <hr> some thing horizontal
            
            <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org" target='_blank'>this is an example of a web page</a>
        </p>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

One thing to note perhaps is the use of `target='_blank'` in the hyperlink. This opens the link in a new window/tab so that the original page remains open ~ you do not want, afterall, to send away visitors! But, as already noted - use the scheme when adding remote links else they will be treated as relative to current site.

```
<img src='//example.com/images/img1.jpg' />
<script src='//example.com/script.js'></script> ...etc
```

For certain types of content (img,css,javascript etc) you may omit the scheme but instead use a double slash `//` - this forces the content to load using the same protocol as the current page.

Comment: thanks but , noob over here , no need to scare me off , by the way , i stole your code❤

Comment: `"i stole your code"` - good, it was intended for you to further your learning. If it helps I am glad